# Android webview android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table passwordtb already exists

Tags: android, webview

In our SDK,We use webview to load ads. And one developer seed to us the log
,

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table passwordtb already exists (code 1)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:743)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1706)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1635)
       at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.PasswordDatabase.createTable(PasswordDatabase.java:149)
       at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.PasswordDatabase.initDatabase(PasswordDatabase.java:140)
       at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.PasswordDatabase.initOnBackgroundThread(PasswordDatabase.java:108)
       at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.PasswordDatabase.access$000(PasswordDatabase.java:13)
       at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.PasswordDatabase$1.run(PasswordDatabase.java:92)
```

I want to knew why is it.

Comment: Also, share your **DatabaseOpenHelper** class in  which you have created your **table**.

Comment: We never create passwordtb table. So I can't share DatabaseOpenHelper class